# What does "non-cpu profiled classes" means in the JProfiler classes telemetry?

Tags: jprofiler

I am running the sample program in JProfiler. 
Then I am confused by the telemetry line "Non-cpu profiled classes" in the classes telemetry. Does it mean the classes of the sample program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Non-CPU profiled" classes are those that are not included in the filter settings. For the sample session, the classes that make up the sample are profiled, while all other classes that are loaded in the JVM are not profiled.

Comment: Session->Session Settings in the menu, then change to the "Filter settings" tab.